# Different axis limits per facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a faceted plot in `ggplot2` where the y axis shows labels and the x axis should show line graphs with the value for each label in two different measures (which are on different scales). So far I have this:

```
Data <- structure(list(label = structure(
  c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
  4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
  facet = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
  1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.0108889081049711, 
  0.37984336540103, 0.0232500876998529, 0.777756493305787, 
  0.0552913920022547, 0.920194681268185, 0.0370863009011373, 
  0.114463779143989, 0.00536034172400832, 0.469208759721369, 
  0.0412159096915275, 0.587875489378348), group = c(1, 1, 1, 
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("label", "facet", 
  "value", "group"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(Data, aes(x = label, y = value, group = group)) + geom_line() + 
     facet_grid(~ facet, scales = "free") + coord_flip()
```

Which creates the following plot:
[image]

The problem is that the measures are on different scales and I would prefer the `A` plot to have x limits from 0 to 0.1 and the `B` plot to have x limits from 0 to 1. I thought `scales = "free"` should fix this but it doesn't change the plot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I came up with something similar to `df239`:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(y = label, x = value, group=group)) + geom_path() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ facet, scales = "free")
```

Note you have to use `geom_path`, and take care with the ordering of your points because just switching `x` and `y` is not the same as `coord_flip` (which as noted in the other answer isn't supported with `facet_wrap`).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change axes orientation manually, the problem is: *ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip.*

```
ggplot(Data, aes(y = label, x = value, group = group)) + geom_line() + 
 facet_grid(~ facet, scales = "free")
```