# Using geom_boxplot with facet_grid and free_y

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot, axis-labels

This question has been asked [a](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/boxplot-with-respect-to-two-factors-using-ggplot2-in-r) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937127/different-axis-limits-per-facet-in-ggplot2) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735539/ggplot2-boxplot-with-facet-grid-and-free-scale), but I've read them all and cannot find an answer.

```
df <- data.frame(f1=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")), 
                 f2=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("young","old")),
                 boxthis=rnorm(100))
ggplot(aes(y=boxthis, x=f2), data=df) 
  + geom_boxplot() 
  + facet_grid(~f1, scales="free")
```

This generates the plot below, but **the y axis is shared across the facet column**. In my real data, this is a problem as each factor in `f1` needs a widely different axis range. Is there some trick to getting `free` to work here?

[image: plot]

I have found that `free` works as expected when making the facet vertical, as shown below, but this clearly looks horrid compared to making the facet horizontal

```
ggplot(aes(y=boxthis, x=f2), data=df) 
  + geom_boxplot() 
  + facet_grid(f1~., scales="free")
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: Why not just using `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - it works!! I've love to give you credit, would you post an answer? Also if you have any idea why wrap works and grid doesn't it would be good to know. I've never used `facet_wrap` before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll go ahead and post @DavidArenburg's answer here to close out the question. You should use `facet_wrap` rather than `facet_grid`

```
df <- data.frame(f1=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.35), label=c("m","w")), 
                 f2=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.65), label=c("young","old")),
                 boxthis=rnorm(100))
ggplot(aes(y=boxthis, x=f2), data=df) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~f1, scales="free")
```

Basically `facet_grid` tries to align everything nicely so that variable levels are the same across rows and columns in a rectangular layout and it's easy to compare across plots. `facet_wrap` isn't as picky and will just wrap plots into a an arbitrary number of rows and columns. That't why the latter allows you to specify `nrows` and `ncols` and the former does not (it uses the number of levels in the conditioning factor)

[image]