# ggplot2: facets: different axis limits and free space

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display two dimensions in my data, (1) reporting entity in different facets and (2) country associated to the data point on the x-axis. The problem is that the country dimension includes a "total", which is a lot higher than all of the individual values, so I would need an own axis limit for that.

My solution was to try another facetting dimension, but I could not get it working and looking nicely at the same time. Consider the following dummy data:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
country <- c("US","US","UK","World","World","World","US","US","UK","World","World","World")
value <- c(150,40,100,1000,1100,1500,5,10,20,150,200,120)
# + some other dimensions
mydat <- data.frame(id,country,value)

   id country value
1   1      US   150
2   1      US    40
3   1      UK   100
4   1   World  1000
5   1   World  1100
6   1   World  1500
7   2      US     5
8   2      US    10
9   2      UK    20
10  2   World   150
11  2   World   200
12  2   World   120
```

If I use a facet grid to display a world total, the axis limit is forced for the other countries as well:

```
mydat$breakdown <- mydat$country == "World"

ggplot(mydat) + aes(x=country,y=value) + geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(id ~ breakdown,scales = "free",space = "free_x") + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank() , strip.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit( c(0,0,0,0) , units = "lines" ) )
```

(the last part of the plot is just to remove the additional strip).

[image: facet grid plot]

If I use a facet wrap, it does give me different axis limits for each plot, but then I cannot pass the `space = "free_x"` argument, meaning that the single column for the total will consume the same space as the entire country overview, which looks ugly for data sets with many countries:

```
ggplot(mydat) + aes(x=country,y=value) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(id ~ breakdown,scales = "free")
```

[image: facet wrap plot]

There are several threads here which ask similar questions, but none of the answers helped me to achieve this yet.

[Different axis limits per facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937127/different-axis-limits-per-facet-in-ggplot2)

[Is it yet possible to have different axis breaks / limits for individual facets in ggplot with free scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819333/is-it-yet-possible-to-have-different-axis-breaks-limits-for-individual-facets)

[Setting individual axis limits with facet_wrap and scales = "free" in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046051/setting-individual-axis-limits-with-facet-wrap-and-scales-free-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try `gridExtra::grid.arrange` or `cowplot::plot_grid`:

```
lst <- split(mydat, list(mydat$breakdown, mydat$id))
plots <- lapply(seq(lst), function(x) {ggplot(lst[[x]]) + 
    aes(x=country,y=value) + 
    geom_point() + 
    ggtitle(names(lst)[x]) + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
})
do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, 
        c(plots, list(ncol=2, widths=c(2/3, 1/3)), 
          left="Value", bottom="country"))
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks!! Just a few additions make it really nice:

(1)

Remove the prefixes: 

`names(lst) <- gsub("TRUE.","",names(lst))` and `names(lst) <- gsub("FALSE.","",names(lst))`.

(2) 

Make the column widths dynamic: 

`t <- length(unique(mydat$country[mydat$breakdown]))` 

`f <- length(unique(mydat$country[!(mydat$breakdown)]))` 

and then replace the column widths with `f/(t+f)` and `t/(t+f)`. There are probably more efficient ways to do it, but I'm still starting out with R (ggplot being one of the reasons for switching from Matlab :)).

Comment: You might wannt to check out `cowplot::plot_grid`, too, which allows you to align the axes: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html